# How to get real width and height of the screen in the bada widget?

Tags: javascript, bada, samsung-mobile

Does anyone know how to get REAL width and height of the screen in the bada (Samsung Wave) widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**widget.window.resizeWindow(width, height);**

i hope it will be helpfull to someone